# Remove items of the list if impossible to cast Python

Tags: python

through this small function I want to cast the second column (row[2]) of a list named data.

```
def apply_float(rows):
    for row in rows:
        try:
            row[2] = float(row[2])
        except:
            print (row[2])


apply_float(data)
```

However what I would like, in case of error, is removing the entire row. Is there a simple way to do that ? Sorry for asking this, I think it may be easy but I'm still learning ! :]

Comment: Please provide a sample input `data` by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53283319/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a filtered list and use slice assignment in order to mutate the passed list accordingly without repeatedly doing expensive remove operations:

```
def apply_float(rows):
    cleaned = []
    for row in rows:
        try:
            row[2] = float(row[2])
            cleaned.append(row)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):  # always narrow down 
            print(row[2])
    rows[:] = cleaned  # mutates passed list
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed ! I will keep this exemple in mind to work on other functions ! thank you !

Comment: Wouldn't resetting the reference, `rows=cleaned`, be just as good?

Comment: Nope, that would just rebind the local variable `rows`, but the passed list object (`data`) would remain unaltered.

Comment: I meant specifically here, somehow i got the impression OP does not care about the initial object, but I guess that was inference on my part.

Comment: @kabanus Without returning `cleaned`, removing the slice will leave the function without any visible effect to the caller. Note that `rows` is not an accessible variable to someone calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

Not in one go on the same list with usual iterating, as you cannot delete stuff from a list you are iterating on. You could on the other hand make it pretty efficient using the `yield` keyword in a generator:

```
def apply_float(rows):
    for row in rows:
        try:
            yield row[:2]+[float(row[2])]+row[3:] #drop the last part if only 3 columns
        except (ValueError,TypeError):
            pass

data = list(apply_float(data))
```

so only the "good" rows are yielded. You do not have to convert this to a list - only do that if you need this list for more than a single iteration, as you can iterate the generator as is.

If you want to actually mutate the object you would still need `data[:] = ...`.

Comment: this is an interesting option also ! I understand better the yield keyword and how lists are working

Answer (score 0):

what about this :

```
def apply_float(rows):
    new_data = []
    for row in rows:
        try:
            new_data.append(float(row[2]))
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            print(row[2])
    return new_data


data = apply_float(data)
```

Comment: I would explicitly catch the ValueError and TypeError rather than use a catch-all except here

Answer (score 0):

I would probably not modify the original scraped_data, even if you don't need the original. Return a new generator instead, and convert to a collection when you need it, or maybe you can use generator and avoid allocating memory for the whole collection:

```
def apply_float(rows):
    for row in rows:
        try:
            row[2] = float(row[2])
            yield row
        except:
            print(row[2])

filtered_data = apply_float(data)

# original
print(data)

# filtered
print(list(filtered_data))
```

Answer (score -1):

First, iterate through rows with an index... then this is trivial.

```
def apply_float(rows):
    index = 0
    while index < len(rows):
        try:
            rows[index][2] = float(rows[index][2])
            index += 1
        except:
            print (rows[index][2])
            rows.pop(index)

apply_float(data)
```

Comment: I acknowledge that this is the naïve approach, but why the downvote?